# How to upload and read the xml data from local file using angular 2 or above?

Tags: xml, angular, file-upload, xml-parsing

I have a requirement where in , I need to upload the xml file present on the local machine using file input, read the xml data from the file and pass that xml data to the Api. Can anyone please help me out, is there any way that it can be achieved.

Thanks

I expect the xml data from the local file to be captured into a variable in angular

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with an input like this one in the template:

```
<input type="file" id="file-input" (change)="readFile($event)" />
```

Then in the component this is declaration of the readFile function:

```
readFile = (e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        if (!file) {
            return;
        }
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (evt) => {
            const xmlData: string = (evt as any).target.result;
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }
```